# maven parameters tomcat7 plugin

Tags: maven-3

I want to be able to run the following command using maven

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

I also want to add the update parameter as specified

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

How do I add update true to the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the configuration element:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
         <update>true</update>
         <url>http://www.mydomain.com:1234/mymanager</url>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html